# attempting to take millseconds from column and translate to date format

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a udacity.com tutorial

I'm having trouble with syntax.

I am attempting to grad a list of rows, grab the contents of the `'ts` column. which is in milliseconds

and return a list of date formats. of the format `format='%H%d%U%B%Y%A'`

I am getting the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-16-66d05f14b2ae>", line 1
    t = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[[df['ts']], format='%H%d%U%B%Y%A', errors='ignore'])
                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

but let's walk this through.

`pd` is the import of `pandas`: `import pandas as pd`

`to_datetime` is a pandas function

`df` is the current dataframe

`.loc` gets multiple rows

`df['ts']` get the actual contents of the column

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have too many brackets. df.loc[[df['ts']] Should be df.loc[df['ts']]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
t = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[[df['ts']], format='%H%d%U%B%Y%A', errors='ignore'])
```

is giving you invalid syntax because of this:

```
t = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[[df['ts']], format='%H%d%U%B%Y%A', errors='ignore'])
                                                                           #^
                                                #you closed a square bracket without any open bracket
```

Corrected:

```
t = pd.to_datetime(df.loc[[df['ts'], format='%H%d%U%B%Y%A', errors='ignore'])
```

So basically, you only had 2 open square brackets and 3 close brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some mismatched brackets at `df.loc[[df['ts']]`.